# import packege or module with Python

Tags: python, import, module

I have a project Python organized like that :

- folder 'src'
- folder 'test'

in my folder src I have a class called Gallery

How to do an import of this class Gallery in a script in my folder "test" ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can add paths to your runtime to make it available for the whole run of your script :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/of/other/imports')
import stuff_from_folder
```

Comment: that gives an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: To explain the solution: when python tried to import something it look to find the file at every directory stored inside the sys.path list. By appending the path to 'src' folder to the sys.path list you effectively make python search there too.